# Second display detected but won't work on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I'm having a problem with second display which doesn't work but seems to be detected. The configuration of my setup is:
PC:

- gigabyte z170x gaming 3 motherboard
- Intel Core i5-660K
- GTX 1060 graphics card
- Two displays: Dell P2719HC daisy chained (connected with DisplayPort to the graphics card)
- dual boot: M.2 NVMe with Windows 10 installed + sata ssd with ubuntu 22.04 installed
- using nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-515

Here is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-2.8 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-2.1.8 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Boot time also takes much time - after I choose Ubuntu os from Grub menu it takes around 40-50 seconds till I see the login screen and during that time displays receives no signal (usually it was some welcome screen).
Also, when I choose to boot from a recovery mode there is no problem with displays - both screens are working as expected (and nothing changes in the configuration) and the boot time is fast.

Also I'm using Dell D6000 docking station (displays **are not connected to it**), with Ethernet plugged in it, but it fails randomly, causing the need to re-plug it directly to the motherboard sockets.

Any help will be appreciated (struggling with this one for some time already, along with dual boot installation).

System is upgraded. Tried to repair broken packages, but nothing seems to be broken.
Tried to re-install Ubuntu several time, with no success (I do manual installation - "something else" option during installation, with swap and efi areas defined, and Windows boot loader selected for "Device for boot loader installation"); tried with CSM enabled and disabled (MBR and GPT boot media accordingly used).

Comment: Are you sure you mean the monitors are daisy chained? That means one is connected to the computer and the second connects to the first but not to the computer.

Comment: That is correct - there is only one DisplayPort cable connected to the pc (to discrete graphic card)

Comment: I do not think anything you do will change the way it is working. Personally I am surprised this works at all.

Comment: Is there a reason you think it should not work? I have been working with that setup for around 2 years already, both on Windows and Linux (it uses DP Multi Stream Transport)